# Paginate data from multiple hosts and databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have two databases on different hosts.They have the same structure.I am using php pdo to connect to these databases and get the data but the problem is that there is a lot of data so i have to include pagination.

Considering that i am making two connections and two queries i cant use LIMIT and OFFSET properly.Is there a way to get this data in one query and then use LIMIT and OFFSET?

Comment: "I have two databases on different hosts." OK, but why?

Comment: Did you try to set up clustering but ended up with two different databases on different hosts with same structure?

Comment: I didnt set those databases up,those are actually different wordpress sites on different hosts so now i have to gather data on a single page.

Comment: If you really must use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` with a query, there's only one thing that comes in my mind. Set up a local database and import data from both remote hosts to your local one. Set up a cron job to import the data once or twice a day (depends on you) automatically and then set up the query with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` from the local database, which contains the data from both remote hosts.

Comment: I dont have to use LIMIT and OFFSET,but i see no other way of doing it